# The Container is displaying higher than the screen

Tags: html, css

I'm using php htm css, but I'm facing an issue regarding my css container it goes higher than the screen when I insert a lot of elements inside.

it comes like this:

[The container isn't displaying correctly in the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCBQ7.png)

but when I zoom out to 80% or reduce the contents it becomes normal:

[Zoomed out to 80%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZGSb.png)

[Removed some contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6R5g.png)

php & html code:

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">

        <h2>My Profile</h2>
            <img style="width: 150px;" src="../assets/imgs/account.png">

            <h4 class="profileinfo">Employee ID: 
                <span style="font-weight: lighter;">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['emp_code'] ?>
                </span>
            </h4>

            <h4 class="profileinfo">Name: 
                <span style="font-weight: lighter;">
                <?php echo $info['name'] ?>
                </span>
            </h4>

            <h4 class="profileinfo">Email: 
                <span style="font-weight: lighter;">
                <?php echo $info['email'] ?>
                </span>
            </h4>

            <h4 class="profileinfo">Phone number: 
                <span style="font-weight: lighter;">
                <?php echo $info['phone'] ?>
                </span>
            </h4>

            <h4 class="profileinfo">Position: 
                <span style="font-weight: lighter;">
                <?php echo role_to_string($info['role']) ?>
                </span>
            </h4>

            <h4 class="profileinfo">Department: 
                <span style="font-weight: lighter;">
                <?php echo get_dep_name($info['dep_id']) ?>
                </span>
            </h4>

            <h4 class="profileinfo">Employee status:  
                <span style="font-weight: lighter;">
                <?php echo stat_to_string($info['stat']) ?>
                </span>
            </h4>

            <h4 class="profileinfo">Salary:  
                <span style="font-weight: lighter;">
                <?php echo $info['salary'] . " OMR"?>
                </span>
            </h4>
            
            <?php

            ?>
            <hr>
            <a href="menu.php">Return to Main Menu</a>
        </div>  
    </div>
    </body>
```

css code:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Marhey', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f7fa 0%, #c3cfe2 100%);
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}
```

I tried many solutions like:

```css
.container {
    overflow: auto;}
```

```css
.container {
    min-height: 200px;
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
```

I want the container always be something like when it have less contents and whenever contents become more I just scroll down to see it. I believe it is a simple issue but I don't have enough knowledge to fix it.

Comment: Remove `height: 100vh` from the body or change it to `min-height: 100vh`.

Comment: still didn't work with me

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!!

Apparently the line `margin:0;`
in the body  is causing this issue
I just changed it to `margin:15px;`